# i dont understand why my super() is producing an error

Tags: python, class, object, arguments, super

Why does my programm work if i code like this:

```
class Shape:

    class Shape:
    shape_type = ""

    def __init__(self, c='*'):
        self.color = c

class Square(Shape):
    shape_type = "Quadrat"

    def __init__(self, w, *args, **kwargs):
        Shape.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._width = w

q1 = Square(4, c="#")
```

but not if i use the super() function

```
class Shape:
    shape_type = ""

    def __init__(self, c='*'):
        self.color = c

class Square(Shape):
    shape_type = "Quadrat"

    def __init__(self, w, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self._width = w

q1 = Square(4, c="#")
```

it says TypeError: **init**() got multiple values for argument 'c'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `self`:

```
class Shape:
    shape_type = ""

    def __init__(self, c='*'):
        self.color = c

class Square(Shape):
    shape_type = "Quadrat"

    def __init__(self, w, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self._width = w

q1 = Square(4, c="#")
```

When using `super()`, you don't have to provide the `self` argument, as you're performing the `__init__` on the instance, not the class.